# Google Maps marker clustering doesn't work

Tags: javascript, google-maps, cluster-computing

I have an issue with the marker clustering on this http://libris.houston-1.hybridmedia.be/nl/het-project/ (the gmap is on bottom).

I've included the markerclusterer.js file and intiliazed the clustering with:

```
var mc = new MarkerClusterer(map);
```

The uncompressed JS file can be found here:
http://libris.houston-1.hybridmedia.be/wp-content/themes/bb-theme-child/dist/assets/js/app.js?ver=4.9.8

What am I doing wrong? Is it maybe the order when I'm initializing the clustering?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: Below is the attached screenshot of your webite after I locally replaced the app.js with below code.]
I tested below code on your website and it worked. You can replace your app.js code with below code.

```
var map;
var markers = [];

/* KAART FILTER */

// Klik op de input opvangen
jQuery(function () {
    jQuery('input[name=filter]').change(function () {
      var filterklikid = jQuery(this).attr('id');
      MarkersFilter(filterklikid);
  });
});

// Marker tonen of verbergen aan de hand van de staat van de input
function MarkersFilter(category){
   if (document.getElementById(category).checked===false) { // Verberg de marker
      for (var i=0;i<markers.length;i++) {
         if (markers[i].properties==category)  {
            markers[i].setVisible(false);
         }
      }
   } else { // Toon de marker
      for (var i=0;i<markers.length;i++) {
         if (markers[i].properties==category)  {
            markers[i].setVisible(true);
         }
      }
   }
}

/* EINDE KAART FILTER */

/* ICONEN VOOR VERSCHILLENDE TYPES */

var iconBase = '/mapshapes/';
        var icons = {
          scholen: {
            icon :{
              url: iconBase + 'scholen_maps.svg',
              scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(35, 35),
              origin: new google.maps.Point(0,0),
              anchor: new google.maps.Point(0, 0)
            }
          },
          handel: {
            icon: {
              url: iconBase + 'handel_maps.svg',
              scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(35, 35),
              origin: new google.maps.Point(0,0),
              anchor: new google.maps.Point(0, 0)
            }
          },
          cultuur: {
            icon:{
              url: iconBase + 'cultuur_maps.svg',
              scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(35, 35),
              origin: new google.maps.Point(0,0),
              anchor: new google.maps.Point(0, 0)
            }
          },
          gezondheid: {
            icon:{
              url : iconBase + 'gezondheid_maps.svg',
              scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(35, 35),
              origin: new google.maps.Point(0,0),
              anchor: new google.maps.Point(0, 0)
            }
          },
          sport: {
            icon:{
              url: iconBase + 'sport_maps.svg',
              scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(35, 35),
              origin: new google.maps.Point(0,0),
              anchor: new google.maps.Point(0, 0)
            }
          },
          veiligheid: {
            icon:{
              url: iconBase + 'veiligheid_maps.svg',
              scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(35, 35),
              origin: new google.maps.Point(0,0),
              anchor: new google.maps.Point(0, 0)
            }
          },
          horeca: {
            icon:{
              url: iconBase + 'horeca_maps.svg',
              scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(35, 35),
              origin: new google.maps.Point(0,0),
              anchor: new google.maps.Point(0, 0)
            }
          },
          openbaarvervoer: {
            icon:{
              url: iconBase + 'openbaarvervoer_maps.svg',
              scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(35, 35),
              origin: new google.maps.Point(0,0),
              anchor: new google.maps.Point(0, 0)
            }
          },
          libris: {
            icon:{
              url: iconBase + 'libris.png',
              scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(70, 70),
              origin: new google.maps.Point(0,0),
              anchor: new google.maps.Point(0, 0)
            }
          }
        };

function loadMarkers(map) {

  var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
  geojson_url = '/project.geojson';

  jQuery.getJSON(geojson_url, function(result) {
      data = result['locations'];
      jQuery.each(data, function(key, val) {
        var point = new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(val['geometry']['coordinates'][0]), parseFloat(val['geometry']['coordinates'][1]));
        var titleText = val['properties']['name'];    
        var address = val['geometry']['address'];
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
           position: point,
           title: titleText,
           icon: icons[val['type']].icon,
           map: map,
           properties: val['type']
        });
        var markerInfo = "<div><h3>" + titleText + "</h3> " + address + "</div>";
        marker.addListener('click', function() {
          infoWindow.close();
          infoWindow.setContent(markerInfo);
          infoWindow.open(map, marker);
        });
        markers.push(marker);
      });
      var Marker = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers, {imagePath: 'https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/markerclusterer/m'});
      Marker.addMarkers(markers);

  });
}

/* MAP AANMAKEN */
function initMap() {
    map_options = {
      zoom: 16,
      center: {lat: 50.808757, lng: 4.314472},
      styles: [
    {
        "featureType": "administrative",
        "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
        "stylers": [
            {
                "color": "#444444"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "featureType": "landscape",
        "elementType": "all",
        "stylers": [
            {
                "color": "#f2f2f2"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "featureType": "poi",
        "elementType": "all",
        "stylers": [
            {
                "visibility": "off"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "featureType": "road",
        "elementType": "all",
        "stylers": [
            {
                "saturation": -100
            },
            {
                "lightness": 45
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "featureType": "road.highway",
        "elementType": "all",
        "stylers": [
            {
                "visibility": "simplified"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "featureType": "road.arterial",
        "elementType": "labels.icon",
        "stylers": [
            {
                "visibility": "off"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "featureType": "transit",
        "elementType": "all",
        "stylers": [
            {
                "visibility": "off"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "featureType": "water",
        "elementType": "all",
        "stylers": [
            {
                "color": "#46bcec"
            },
            {
                "visibility": "on"
            }
        ]
    }
]
    }


    map_document = document.getElementById('projectmap');
    map = new google.maps.Map(map_document,map_options);
    loadMarkers(map);
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initMap);
```

[image: This is what you have in your website as on today, i.e. 20-August-2018]

Comment: I've copied your code in my project, but still got the "MarkerCluster is not defined" error. The live code is over here: http://libris.houston-1.hybridmedia.be/nl/het-project/

I don't know what I'm doing wrong as this is exactly the same code as yours.

Comment: please ? :) it’s exactly your code, But I get that error

Comment: I verified that your website doesn't have the same code as I pasted in my last answer. To bring your attention to that, Please see, in my code there is no line prior to " function loadMarkers(){ " which calls new MarkerClusterer. Where as on your website (I have attached a latest screenshot in new answer), the code has this line just before this function definition. So, yeah the code is not exactly the same that I posted in my answer. Can't help more than this.

Comment: Sorry, strange but it seems I've probably copied something wrong.
Many thanks for your time and help ! 

Now I'm extending it to exclude 1 marker out of the cluster.

Comment: Please let us know which code worked for you, by accepting that as answer.

Comment: Alright done :) I've accepted the correct answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

After pushing all the markers in the array inside loadMarkers method, you are not calling the MarkerCluster api. You need to call MasterCluster.addMarkers(markers) after jquery.each loop.

Also you need to store the reference of MasterCluster instance on line no. 99 in app.js and pass that to loadMarker method so that addMarkers api can be called on it.

Comment: I've added MasterCluster.addMarkers(markers) after markers.push(marker)
But now I get the console error "MarkerCluster is not defined.
I don't understand what you mean with "store the reference and pass that to loadMarker. Sorry

Comment: Can you please show me whats the final code that you have written?

Comment: I found that you have used mc variable. now pass that mc variable to loadMarkers function as an argument.   loadMarkers(mc);

Comment: my final code is here: http://libris.test/wp-content/themes/bb-theme-child/dist/assets/js/app-test.js?ver=4.9.6 
This one gives the error

Comment: Please see I edited my first answer. It is self explanatory. Make the changes as per that, and you will sail through.

Comment: I've added everything from your latest answer: http://libris.houston-1.hybridmedia.be/wp-content/themes/bb-theme-child/dist/assets/js/app.js?ver=4.9.8

But I still got the "MarkerCluster is not defined" error. This error is on: 

    var mc = new MarkerCluster(map);

Comment: It seems that the markerclusterer.js library isn't properly loaded. The path is correct, but even if I delete the include, I get the same error "MarkerCluster is not deflined"

Comment: from which line do you get MarkerCluster is not defined?

Answer (score 0):

First after the initialization on line number 100, store the instance of MarkerCluster in a variable as below.

```
var mc = new MarkerCluster(map);
```

when calling loadMarkers() in next line pass this variable as below:-

```
loadMarkers(mc);
```

Accept the argument in loadMarkers function as follows:--

```
function loadMarkers(markerCluster) { // this markerCluster would be used on last line of this function as shown below.
```

in loadMarkers function after jquery foreach loop, write the below line:-

```
markerCluster.addMarkers(markers);
```

Comment: I still get the error: MarkerCluster is not defined.

http://libris.test/wp-content/themes/bb-theme-child/dist/assets/js/app-test.js?ver=4.9.6

Answer (score 0):

It is better to declare and intialize the markerCluster after loading the markers

```
var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers,{
  imagePath: 'https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/markerclusterer/m',
  zoomOnClick: true
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You had messed up all your code. You didn't implement that I suggested. In case you havent modified anything else, just replace your whole file app.js with below code. I have modified the code and added complete file below.

```
var map;
var markers = [];

/* KAART FILTER */

// Klik op de input opvangen
jQuery(function () {
    jQuery('input[name=filter]').change(function () {
      var filterklikid = jQuery(this).attr('id');
      MarkersFilter(filterklikid);
  });
});

// Marker tonen of verbergen aan de hand van de staat van de input
function MarkersFilter(category){
   if (document.getElementById(category).checked===false) { // Verberg de marker
      for (var i=0;i<markers.length;i++) {
         if (markers[i].properties==category)  {
            markers[i].setVisible(false);
         }
      }
   } else { // Toon de marker
      for (var i=0;i<markers.length;i++) {
         if (markers[i].properties==category)  {
            markers[i].setVisible(true);
         }
      }
   }
}

/* EINDE KAART FILTER */

/* ICONEN VOOR VERSCHILLENDE TYPES */

var iconBase = '/mapshapes/';
        var icons = {
          scholen: {
            icon :{
              url: iconBase + 'scholen_maps.svg',
              scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(35, 35),
              origin: new google.maps.Point(0,0),
              anchor: new google.maps.Point(0, 0)
            }
          },
          handel: {
            icon: {
              url: iconBase + 'handel_maps.svg',
              scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(35, 35),
              origin: new google.maps.Point(0,0),
              anchor: new google.maps.Point(0, 0)
            }
          },
          cultuur: {
            icon:{
              url: iconBase + 'cultuur_maps.svg',
              scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(35, 35),
              origin: new google.maps.Point(0,0),
              anchor: new google.maps.Point(0, 0)
            }
          },
          gezondheid: {
            icon:{
              url : iconBase + 'gezondheid_maps.svg',
              scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(35, 35),
              origin: new google.maps.Point(0,0),
              anchor: new google.maps.Point(0, 0)
            }
          },
          sport: {
            icon:{
              url: iconBase + 'sport_maps.svg',
              scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(35, 35),
              origin: new google.maps.Point(0,0),
              anchor: new google.maps.Point(0, 0)
            }
          },
          veiligheid: {
            icon:{
              url: iconBase + 'veiligheid_maps.svg',
              scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(35, 35),
              origin: new google.maps.Point(0,0),
              anchor: new google.maps.Point(0, 0)
            }
          },
          horeca: {
            icon:{
              url: iconBase + 'horeca_maps.svg',
              scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(35, 35),
              origin: new google.maps.Point(0,0),
              anchor: new google.maps.Point(0, 0)
            }
          },
          openbaarvervoer: {
            icon:{
              url: iconBase + 'openbaarvervoer_maps.svg',
              scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(35, 35),
              origin: new google.maps.Point(0,0),
              anchor: new google.maps.Point(0, 0)
            }
          },
          libris: {
            icon:{
              url: iconBase + 'libris.png',
              scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(70, 70),
              origin: new google.maps.Point(0,0),
              anchor: new google.maps.Point(0, 0)
            }
          }
        };

function loadMarkers(map) {

  var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
  geojson_url = '/project.geojson';

  jQuery.getJSON(geojson_url, function(result) {
      data = result['locations'];
      jQuery.each(data, function(key, val) {
        var point = new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(val['geometry']['coordinates'][0]), parseFloat(val['geometry']['coordinates'][1]));
        var titleText = val['properties']['name'];    
        var address = val['geometry']['address'];
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
           position: point,
           title: titleText,
           icon: icons[val['type']].icon,
           map: map,
           properties: val['type']
        });
        mc.addMarkers(markers);
        var markerInfo = "<div><h3>" + titleText + "</h3> " + address + "</div>";
        marker.addListener('click', function() {
          infoWindow.close();
          infoWindow.setContent(markerInfo);
          infoWindow.open(map, marker);
        });
        markers.push(marker);
      });
      var Marker = new MarkerCluster(map, markers, {imagePath: 'http://localhost/libris/mapshapes/'});
  });
}

/* MAP AANMAKEN */
function initMap() {
    map_options = {
      zoom: 16,
      center: {lat: 50.808757, lng: 4.314472},
      styles: [
    {
        "featureType": "administrative",
        "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
        "stylers": [
            {
                "color": "#444444"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "featureType": "landscape",
        "elementType": "all",
        "stylers": [
            {
                "color": "#f2f2f2"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "featureType": "poi",
        "elementType": "all",
        "stylers": [
            {
                "visibility": "off"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "featureType": "road",
        "elementType": "all",
        "stylers": [
            {
                "saturation": -100
            },
            {
                "lightness": 45
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "featureType": "road.highway",
        "elementType": "all",
        "stylers": [
            {
                "visibility": "simplified"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "featureType": "road.arterial",
        "elementType": "labels.icon",
        "stylers": [
            {
                "visibility": "off"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "featureType": "transit",
        "elementType": "all",
        "stylers": [
            {
                "visibility": "off"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "featureType": "water",
        "elementType": "all",
        "stylers": [
            {
                "color": "#46bcec"
            },
            {
                "visibility": "on"
            }
        ]
    }
]
    }


    map_document = document.getElementById('projectmap');
    map = new google.maps.Map(map_document,map_options);
    loadMarkers(map);
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initMap);
```

Comment: already thank you for your help. I've copied you code, but I get an error on line 129: mc.addMarkers(markers); (Uncaught ReferenceError: mc is not defined)

Comment: You can find the latest code over here: http://libris.houston-1.hybridmedia.be/nl/het-project/ scroll down a little bit to see the map.